# TypeScript + ES6 + .system.js + d.td + extends

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

As in TypeScript in combination with ES6 + system.js to create a declarative class .d.ts, to classes described therein could be used for expansion of custom class?

Or to paraphrase the question, how to make this code work?

*some.d.ts*

```
declare module SOME {
    export class SomeSuperClass{
        constructor();
        execute();
    }
    export class SomeSubClass{
        constructor();
        execute();
    }
}

declare module 'some.js' {
    export = SOME;
}
```

*main.ts*

```
export class Main {
    constructor() {
        console.log('typescript main ');
        new Test();
    }
}
```

*test.ts*

```
import SOME from 'some.js';

export default class Test extends SOME.SomeSuperClass{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: It definitely shoul be `import {SomeSuperClass} from 'some.js'` and `export default class Test extends SomeSuperClass {…}` and `import Test from 'test.ts'`, but I don't know what annotations TS wants for that.

Comment: @Bergi: `import {SomeSuperClass} from 'some.js'` === `error TS1192: Module ''some.js'' has no default export.`

Comment: That makes no sense - `{SomeSuperClass}` is not a default import. TS does use ES6 module syntax, right?

Comment: @Bergi: Trying to compile to es5 and es6, but the result is the same. Compile with gulp-typescript. Doing this in order to understand and alter existing code for the library, which I for the same reason, can't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues with your files:

- You have to export SOME module to be able to import it, you imported it in test.ts
- The import of SOME in test.ts was using a "default" import format. you should have used the implicit format. {SOME}
- You forgot to import Test in your main.ts (Here you used the "default" import/export)

Here are the files as they should have been written:

some.d.ts

```
export module SOME {
    export class SomeSuperClass{
        constructor();
        execute();
    }
    export class SomeSubClass{
        constructor();
        execute();
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import Test from 'test';

export class Main {
    constructor() {
        console.log('typescript main ');
        new Test();
    }
}
```

test.ts

```
import {SOME} from 'some';

export default class Test extends SOME.SomeSuperClass{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```